# Incorrect syntax near ','. Must declare the scalar variable "@checkIn".'

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to show the list bill when I click "ViewBill" button. But i get an exception

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.
Must declare the scalar variable "@checkIn".'

This is my code

**SQL**

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[USP_GetListBillByDate] 
@checkIn date, @checkOut date 
AS 
BEGIN      
      SELECT t.name , b.totalPrice , DateCheckIn,DateCheckOut      
      FROM dbo.Bill AS b, dbo.TableFood AS t      
      WHERE DateCheckIn >= @checkIn AND DateCheckOut <= @checkOut AND b.status = 1      
      AND t.id = b.idTable 
END
```

**BillDAO**

```
public DataTable GetBillListByDate(DateTime checkIn, DateTime checkOut) 
{ 
   return DataProvider.Instance.ExecuteQuery("exec USP_GetListBillByDate @checkIn,@checkOut", new object[] {checkIn, checkOut}); 
}
```

**AdminManager**

```
void LoadDateTimePickerBill() 
{    
  DateTime today = DateTime.Now;    
  dtpFromDate.Value = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);    
  dtpToDate.Value = dtpFromDate.Value.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1); 
}
 void LoadListBillByDate(DateTime checkIn, DateTime checkOut) 
{
   dgvBill.DataSource = BillDAO.Instance.GetBillListByDate(checkIn, checkOut); 
} 
private void  btnViewBill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{    
   LoadListBillByDate(dtpFromDate.Value, dtpToDate.Value); 
}
```

**DataProvider**

```
public DataTable ExecuteQuery(string query, object[] parameter = null)
        {
            DataTable data = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionSTR))
            {
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

                if (parameter != null)
                {
                    string[] listPara = query.Split(' ');
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (string item in listPara)
                    {
                        if (item.Contains('@'))
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(item, parameter[i]);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

                adapter.Fill(data);

                connection.Close();
            }

            return data;
        }
```

I try to research and fix but this exception still exists.

Comment: What does `DataProvider.Instance.ExecuteQuery` do, where does it come from? Is it an ORM? You probably need something like `DataProvider.Instance.ExecuteQueryInterpolated($"exec USP_GetListBillByDate @checkIn = {checkIn}, @checkOut = {@checkOut}")` Side note: don't use comma-joins, that's really old hat, use proper `JOIN` syntax instead.

Comment: I just added Dataprovider. It is used to process to pour the data into the gridView. Can u tell me where I'm wrong

Comment: I'd suggest using a library like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) instead of trying to roll your own. The way the code tries to determine the parameter names by splitting on whitespace won't work. In this case it used `@checkIn,@checkOut` as a parameter name. Even if you add a space, you'd end with another invalid name, `@checkIn,`. The same thing with Dapper would be `var results=connection.Query<SomeType>( "USP_GetListBillByDate ", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,new {checkIn, checkOut});`

Comment: Notice that `new {checkIn,checkOut}` is an anoymous type with fields named `checkIn` and `checkOut`. Dapper uses reflection to determine the names and generate strongly typed parameters from the fields and values. Dapper also handles opening and closing the connection which means you can eliminate `ExecuteQuery` completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of "generic" data access functions. Ideally you should tailor each to the exact query you are running. That way you can specify the correctparameter type. Or just use Dapper or another ORM.

But your primary issues here are:

- You should use `CommandType.StoredProcedure` to call procedures.
- Even for regular queries, do not attempt to work out what the parameter names are. That's a recipe for disaster.
  Instead just pass them through from the outer function. You can use a `string, object` tuple.
- You are also missing some `using`

```cs
public DataTable ExecuteProcedure(string query, params (string name, object value) parameters = null) =>   // for text queries
    ExecuteQuery(query, CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters);

public DataTable ExecuteProcedure(string query, params (string name, object value) parameters = null) =>   // for procedures
    ExecuteQuery(query, CommandType.Text, parameters);

public DataTable ExecuteQuery(string query, CommandType commandType,
    params (string name, object value) parameters = null)
{
    DataTable data = new DataTable();

    using SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionSTR);
    connection.Open();
    using SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    command.CommandType = commandType;

    if (parameters != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.name, item.value);
        }
    }

    using SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    adapter.Fill(data);
    return data;
}
```

Then call it like this (note that `EXEC` is not used, and the parameters are not specified, in the string. It's just the procedure name).

```cs
return DataProvider.Instance.ExecuteProcedure("dbo.USP_GetListBillByDate",
    ("@checkIn", checkIn),
    ("@checkOut", checkOut));
```

Consider using `async` code if possible.

Comment: Correct way to do this. Never run a sp call as a "exec" statement like a dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

you most likely have a problem in highlighting the `@checkIn`,`@checkOut` parameters - there is no space here, and `query.Split(' ');` does not work correctly

Try this

```
public DataTable GetBillListByDate(DateTime checkIn, DateTime checkOut) 
{ 
    return DataProvider.Instance.ExecuteQuery("exec USP_GetListBillByDate @checkIn, @checkOut", new object[] {checkIn, checkOut});
}
```